# $ajax is being send but is missing a value

Tags: ajax, jquery

Ok, so my script tries to request from php results from mysql and load them into a div. The results are based on nid value which is has to send this value is extracted from id="record-#" the record- is removed and the # is left to be used by ajax as id for the nid.

here is the ajax data function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".note").live('click',function() {
      $("#note_utm_con").show();
      $("#note_utm_nt").html("<img src='http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/4.gif' />");

      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "_class/view.php",
         data: "ajax=1&nid=" + parent.attr('id'),
         success: function(html){
            $("#note_utm").html(html);
            $("#note_utm_nt").html("");
         },
         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {$("#note_utm_nt").html(errorThrown);}
      });
   });

   $("#note_utm_con_cls").click(function() {
     $("#note_utm_con").hide();
    });
});
```

and here is the rest of the page

```
       <div id="note_utm_con" style="display: none;">
<button id="note_utm_con_cls" style="width: 20px;float: right; padding: 2px;clear: both;">X</button>
<div id="note_utm"></div>
<div id="note_utm_nt"></div>
</div>

<?php

class notes {

     var $host;
     var $username;
     var $password;
     var $table;

     public function display_notes() {

         $q = "SELECT * FROM `notice` ORDER BY nid ASC LIMIT 12";
         $r = mysql_query($q);


         if ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
         while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {

             $nid = stripslashes($a['nid']);
             $note = stripslashes($a['note']);
             $type = stripslashes($a['type']);
             $private = stripslashes($a['private']);
             $date = stripslashes($a['date']);
             $author = stripslashes($a['author']);

             if($type == 1) { 
             $type = "posted a comment."; $icon = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Basic_set2_Png/16/megaphone.png"; 
             } elseif($type == 2) { 
             $type = "raised a support ticket."; $icon = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/help_16.png";
             } elseif($type == 3) {
             $type = "added new photo."; $icon = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Basic_set2_Png/16/photo.png";
             } elseif($type == 4) {
             $type = "updated profile details."; $icon = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Basic_set2_Png/16/user_info.png";
             } else { }

             $entry_display .= <<<ENTRY_DISPLAY
             <ul class="list">
             <li id="$nid">
             <a href="javascript:;" id="$nid" onClick="retun false;" class="note">
             <img src="$icon" /> 
             $author, 
             $type           
             </a>
             </li>
             </ul>
ENTRY_DISPLAY;

            }

        } else {

            $entry_display = <<<ENTRY_DISPLAY
             <ul class="list">
             <li> 
             <p>
             <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/monitor_16.png" /> 
             Nothing to display
             </p>
             </li>
             </ul>
ENTRY_DISPLAY;
    }

    return $entry_display;
    }

      public function connect() {
      mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password) or die("Could not connect. " . mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db($this->table) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());

      return $this;
      }

      private function note_type() {

             if($type == 1) { $type = "posted a comment!"; } elseif($type == 2) { $type = "raised a support ticket!"; } else { }
             return $type;
      }

}


?>
```

so when a LI with a class="note" is clicked it triggers AJAX call. The call then uses the ID in the href to extract the $nid from the id="record-

In my case it seems as AJAX is sending the request since view.php returns the fields where the data should be but it does not seem to pass much needed nid so PHP is uable to select proper nid from MySQL to use.

Can some one tell me whats wrong with it and how it can be fixed to get the id?`enter code here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotation marks are wrong.  Try this:

```
data: "ajax=1&nid=" + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
```

---

Edit: Unless you haven't posted the full code still, you don't actually set `parent` anywhere.  This means that you will use the `window.parent` object, which surprisingly enough doesn't have an `id`.  You should use `this.parentNode.id` instead:

```
data: "ajax=1&nid=" + this.parentNode.id,
```

Comment: that causes loading animation to be displayed and nothing else

Comment: @PTDesu You're going to need to give us more information on your jQuery call then.

Comment: O.o and this took me 2hours of time bashing my head into the desk. Aldo how did I miss this I ran a quick look on jQuerys Documentation site on parents and missed this definitely sad. Well thanks for help this pretty much works as I have already tested it

Comment: Yep, funny still that I missed it, and the things that you need seem to be hidden but when you found what you needed its right there, and then you wonder "how did I miss it?" funny thing

Answer (score 2):

From what you've written it looks as if you're passing the parent.attr("id") replace call as a string rather than extracting the variable:

```
data: "ajax=1&nid=" + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
```

Comment: actually I can remove replace from the data call since I can just call id via id=# since this is running in a file which is the called by other file via load function in jQuery, but even so just using data: "ajax=1&nid=" + parent.attr('id') it seems to be just showing loading animation and nothing else.